# Spring Kafka Multiple Schema registries with Multiple Kafka Templates

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, aws-glue

From [Spring Kafka 2.5 onwards it is possible to have multiple Kafka templates based on different producer config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=Starting%20with%20version%202.5%2C%20you%20can%20now%20override%20the%20factory%E2%80%99s%20ProducerConfig%20properties%20to%20create%20templates%20with%20different%20producer%20configurations%20from%20the%20same%20factory), from the documentation it seems the templates vary in Key and Value types.

In a Spring boot service,

> Is it possible to have multiple Spring Kafka Templates with same Key
> and Value types, the templates only different in their producer configurations

i.e. for example:

```
KafkaTemplate<String, String> defaultKafkaTemplate
KafkaTemplate<String, String> anotherKafkaTemplate
```

If the answer is a yes to the above question:

> Is it possible to have a separate schema registry for each of those
> templates

i.e.

> defaultkafkaTemplate is tied to schema 1 present in Registry A
> anotherkafkaTemplate is tied to schema 10 present in Registry B

I am able to integrate single AWS Glue Schema registry with a Spring Kafka provided KafkaTemplate, was wondering if the above case is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can define two beans:

```java
@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, String> defaultTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, String> otherTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf, Map.of("some.property", "other.value");
}
```

If you define any `KafkaTemplate` bean(s), Boot will not auto configure one.